# SQL CHECK statement error: A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "CHECK" )

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, ddl, magic-draw

I have made relational database model using MagicDraw tool. Every cashier has their workTime type saved in enumerator:

[image]       [image]

Then I generate DDL code and try to paste it into phpMyAdmin to generate DB but I get many errors. I tried to fix them by hand but errors are still here. So how should that check statement be written?

[image: SQL CHECK statement]

Errors:
[image: Errors]

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using and did you consult the manual for that version, as the error suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.

A book that I was following to create DDL from MagicDraw project suggested to pick "Check Constraints" as an "Enumeration transformation strategy" when transforming model. It didnt worked that way so I have chosen "Lookup tables" instead and DDL code seems to be working now.

However it still had some erorrs. I had to add semicolons after all INSERT statements.
[image]

And I also had to delete word "precision" after every 'double' type:
[image: delete]

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

A check constraint isn't part of a column's definition, it's its own clause in the table definition. You need a comma between the `worktime char(13) not null` and the `check`.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints): "CHECK(expression) given as part of a column definition." is one of the two valid forms of check constraint. One of the examples given is `b INT CHECK (b>2)`.